# both sentences are same meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "I can't help laughing at the sight." = "I can't help myself laughing at the sight."

I think that both sentences have same meaning.

What do you think about this?

Please, help me anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are the same.

Even if the word "myself" is omitted, it is nonetheless heavily implied that the reflexive construction "help myself (from)" is being said. For that reason it is something you would expect to encounter more in spoken English than written English, as it is essentially just a case of leaving a word out for brevity.

Comment: @SIS - [Not so fast!  Please read our Meta post on when you should accept an answer.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)  Generally, it's not the best idea to accept the first answer right away, because there might be a better one later.  I would actually say that the second sentence is not really fluent - while it's understandable, it is not really correct; we don't say "help myself *X*ing".

Comment: @stangdon so, Is "help myself from Xing" correct?

Comment: In hindsight, I think stangdon is correct and "from" is necessary.

Comment: @stangdon I've done what you want. Keep it unaccepted.

Comment: @TomB You might consider _ellipsis_ as a less verbose way to say _"leaving a word out for brevity."_